# How to disable TestCafe cookie processing mechanism to allow default browser document.cookie list?

Tags: javascript, testing, cookies, automated-tests, testcafe

I have a business requirement to extract all cookies generated during my test journeys.

But I've come across a similar issue as discussed [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3739), in that TestCafe uses its own cookie processing mechanism. At the end of the test when I log `document.cookie`, I do not get the full same list as when I complete the test journey manually. At least half of the expected 30 cookies are not present when running via TestCafe proxy browser.

Is it possible for me to temporarily disable TestCafe's cookie processing mechanism, to fulfill my requirement?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

The TestCafe cookie processing mechanism cannot be disabled. But if you need to gather all cookies sent with requests, you can use [a request logger](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/logging-http-requests.html#the-request-object) to get cookies from request headers, like in this example:

```js
import _ from "lodash";

import { ClientFunction, RequestLogger, Selector } from "testcafe";

const logger = RequestLogger(/.*/, { logRequestHeaders: true });

const setCookie = ClientFunction(() => { document.cookie = 'foo=bar'; });

fixture `Cookie Test`
    .page('bing.com')
    .requestHooks(logger);

test('Send cookie', async t => {
    await setCookie();
    await t.click(Selector('#sb_go_par'));

    const cookies =
        _.uniq(
            _.flatMap(
                _.filter(
                    _.map(
                        _.flatMap(
                            logger.requests,
                            item => item.request.headers
                        ),
                        headers => headers.cookie
                    )
                ),
                cookies => cookies.split('; ')
            )
        );

    console.log(cookies);
    await t.expect(cookies).contains('foo=bar');
});
```

Also, be aware that `document.cookie` doesn't show HTTP-only cookies and cookies for other domains, while they are visible via DevTools, and that TestCafe runs tests in clear environment every time. So, if you run the test scenario manually to compare results, you will need to do it in incognito mode; otherwise you might get additional cookies from previous sessions.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey Lindberg  Although the line: headers => headers.cookie, shows as an error "Property 'cookie' does not exist on type 'object'." The code still works.

What I can now see from the cookie list is that:
* cookies with full domain are printed: www.testenv1.mycompany.co.uk
* cookies with end domain only are Not printed: .mycompany.co.uk

Comment: @Benny Meade, did I understand you correctly that a half of the cookies are still missing? If TestCafe doesn't send cookies that obviously should be sent, it looks like a bug, and you can report it on GitHub using [this template](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md).

Comment: Yes half of the cookies are still missing using the 'headers => headers.cookie' code example above. I will report this on the link you provided.